# Problem while installing .deb package using Ubuntu Software

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center, deb

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04**. I am having problem while installing softwares. When I open Ubuntu Software, it doesn't load and when I download `.deb` package from external website and open it with Ubuntu Software, it keeps loading forever. I left it to load for 20 minutes but it still keeps loading. How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't often use Ubuntu Software, but from my experience Ubuntu software is painfully slow. For alternative, considered try [gdebi](https://launchpad.net/gdebi). To install, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Other ways is installing via `dpkg`, followed by `apt-get install -f` to fix missing dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/file.deb
```

In the past, you needed to change the working directory to the folder that contained the `.deb` file and run separate commands for `dpkg` and `apt-get`. In 16.04, though, you can simply use the [`apt`](http://www.howtogeek.com/234583/simplify-command-line-package-management-with-apt-instead-of-apt-get/) command:

```
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/file.deb
```

Comment: Love your answer, only thing I've got is that software is indeed painfully slow. I'd like to ask what software's doing differently from dpkg that slows it down. The end result is the same, so there's hardly a reason to do anything differently, yet it seems to... How odd...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it from the command line. See [this extremely popular question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line).

Open the terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and type (where `DEB_PACKAGE`) is the file you're trying to install.

```
sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE
```